# USB_ModeSwitch can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0

Tags: ubuntu, mobile, modem

I use Linux Ubuntu 19.04. 
Modem Huawei 12d1 14db.
I can see that the ethernet connection appeared, and wifi.
But the internet doesn't work.

lsusb
 lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0408:a060 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.075017] printk: console [tty0] enabled

And when I run:
usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x14db

Look for default devices ...
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 009 on bus 001
Error opening the device. Abort

Could you please suggest if the problem with the modem or with the mobile provider?